# Shrink/Zoom/Scale images in image-mode

Tags: images, image-mode, zooming

With Emacs' doc-view-mode I can easily shrink/zoom/etc PDFs, however, I would like to be able to do the same thing with images. Currently when I open an image I cannot adjust the zoom level to fit it to the frame. I know there is `image-mode-fit-frame`, however, it does not help when the image is larger than my screen.

Is there a package or mode that will allow me zoom in and out on an image?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Such functionality is provied by packages:

- [`image-dired-thumbnail-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Image_002dDired.html)

  > With point in the thumbnail buffer, you can type <kbd>RET</kbd> (`image-dired-display-thumbnail-original-image`) to display a sized version of it in another window. **This sizes the image to fit the window.**

  It uses ImageMagick's `convert` command.

  You can also use `image-dired-external-viewer` to avoid the problem and display your images in an external image viewer such as [`feh`](http://feh.finalrewind.org/).
- [`eimp`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/eimp.el)

  ```
  (add-hook 'image-mode-hook 'eimp-mode)
  ```

  It uses the `mogrify` utility from ImageMagick to do the actual transformations.

  ```
  (kbd "+") 'eimp-increase-image-size
  (kbd "-") 'eimp-decrease-image-size
  (kbd "<") 'eimp-rotate-image-anticlockwise
  (kbd ">") 'eimp-rotate-image-clockwise
  (kbd "B +") 'eimp-blur-image
  (kbd "B -") 'eimp-sharpen-image
  (kbd "B E") 'eimp-emboss-image
  (kbd "B G") 'eimp-gaussian-blur-image
  (kbd "B R") 'eimp-radial-blur-image
  (kbd "C B +") 'eimp-increase-image-brightness
  (kbd "C B -") 'eimp-decrease-image-brightness
  (kbd "C C +") 'eimp-increase-image-contrast
  (kbd "C C -") 'eimp-decrease-image-contrast
  (kbd "F ^") 'eimp-flip-image
  (kbd "F >") 'eimp-flop-image
  (kbd "F <") 'eimp-flop-image
  (kbd "N") 'eimp-negate-image

  ; Commands most relevant to you:
  (kbd "S f") 'eimp-fit-image-to-window
  (kbd "S h") 'eimp-fit-image-height-to-window
  (kbd "S w") 'eimp-fit-image-width-to-window

  (kbd "<right>") 'eimp-roll-image-right
  (kbd "<left>") 'eimp-roll-image-left
  (kbd "<up>") 'eimp-roll-image-up
  (kbd "<down>") 'eimp-roll-image-down
  (kbd "<down-mouse-1>") 'eimp-mouse-resize-image
  (kbd "<S-down-mouse-1>") 'eimp-mouse-resize-image-preserve-aspect
  (kbd "C-c C-k") 'eimp-stop-all
  ```
- [`eiv`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/eiv.el) - It also uses the ImageMagick package which should provide `mogrify`.

  Complete command list:

  - `eiv-fit-image-to-window` - **Resize image to current window size.**
  - `eiv-rotate-current-image` - Rotate current image at 90 degrees.
  - `eiv-dec-or-inc-image` - Resize image to current window size.
  - `eiv-diaporama` - Start a diaporama on tree.
  - `eiv-viewer` - The `emacs-image-viewer`. Allows to navigate in a tree of dir and subdir.

Comment: One should note that `eimp` modifies the file. It doesn't work on read-only images.

Answer (score 9):

### Solution

I used the source code in `lisp/image-mode.el` to write this up. Calling this function in any image buffer will resize it to fit to width or height depending on the image and window height/width ratios.

You do need these 2 things for this function to work:

- Your Emacs needs to have been compiled with **ImageMagick**.
- By default `libjpeg` loader is used to handle JPEG images. The hack shown in next part of this answer is used to force emacs to use `imagemagick` loader.

```
(defun modi/image-transform-fit-to-window()
  "Resize the image to fit the width or height based on the image and window ratios.
Imagemagick is required to run this function."
  (interactive)
  (let* ( (img-size (image-display-size (image-get-display-property) t))
          (img-width (car img-size))
          (img-height (cdr img-size))
          (img-h/w-ratio (/ (float img-height) (float img-width)))
          (win-width (- (nth 2 (window-inside-pixel-edges))
                        (nth 0 (window-inside-pixel-edges))))
          (win-height (- (nth 3 (window-inside-pixel-edges))
                         (nth 1 (window-inside-pixel-edges))))
          (win-h/w-ratio (/ (float win-height) (float win-width))))
    ;; Fit image by width if the h/w ratio of window is > h/w ratio of the image
    (if (> win-h/w-ratio img-h/w-ratio)
        (image-transform-fit-to-width)
      ;; Else fit by height
      (image-transform-fit-to-height))))
```

### Hack to force Emacs to use ImageMagick for loading images

After following through the emacs bug reports [`#18797`](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18797), [`#10746`](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10746) and [`#10112`](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10112), the following solution worked for forcing Imagemagick to load images; put it somewhere in your `init.el`:

I have forced Emacs to use ImageMagick only for the image files familiar to me: PNG, TIFF, JPEG, SVG; the rest are kept as default. I have chosen to allow `gif` files to be opened by the default loader as emacs 24.4 has improved support for viewing multi-frame images. The whole regexp is taken from `lisp/image.el`.

```
 (setq image-type-header-regexps
       `(
         ("\\`/[\t\n\r ]*\\*.*XPM.\\*/" . xpm)
         ("\\`P[1-6]\\\(?:\
              \\(?:\\(?:#[^\r\n]*[\r\n]\\)?[[:space:]]\\)+\
              \\(?:\\(?:#[^\r\n]*[\r\n]\\)?[0-9]\\)+\
              \\)\\{2\\}" . pbm)
         ("\\`GIF8[79]a" . gif)
         ;; ("\\`\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n" . png) ;; Uncomment this (and comment the below line) to enable inline PNG images in org-mode
         ("\\`\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n" . imagemagick) ; PNG
         ("\\`[\t\n\r ]*#define \\([a-z0-9_]+\\)_width [0-9]+\n\
              #define \\1_height [0-9]+\n\\(\
              #define \\1_x_hot [0-9]+\n\
              #define \\1_y_hot [0-9]+\n\\)?\
              static \\(unsigned \\)?char \\1_bits" . xbm)
         ;; ("\\`\\(?:MM\0\\*\\|II\\*\0\\)" . tiff)
         ("\\`\\(?:MM\0\\*\\|II\\*\0\\)" . imagemagick) ; TIFF
         ("\\`[\t\n\r ]*%!PS" . postscript)
         ;; ("\\`\xff\xd8" . jpeg) ;; Uncomment this (and comment the below line) to enable inline JPEG images in org-mode
         ("\\`\xff\xd8" . imagemagick)    ; JPEG
         ("\\`\377\330" . imagemagick)    ; JPEG
         (,(let* ((incomment-re "\\(?:[^-]\\|-[^-]\\)")
                  (comment-re (concat "\\(?:!--" incomment-re "*-->[ \t\r\n]*<\\)")))
             (concat "\\(?:<\\?xml[ \t\r\n]+[^>]*>\\)?[ \t\r\n]*<"
                     comment-re "*"
                     "\\(?:!DOCTYPE[ \t\r\n]+[^>]*>[ \t\r\n]*<[ \t\r\n]*" comment-re "*\\)?"
                     "[Ss][Vv][Gg]"))
          ;; . svg)  ;; Uncomment this (and comment the below line) to enable inline SVG images in org-mode
          . imagemagick) ; SVG
         ))
```

### Drawback

- Image types chosen to be loaded by ImageMagick will not show up as inline images in Org mode.

### References

- [`image-transform-fit-to-width`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/image-transform-fit-to-width)
- [`image-transform-fit-to-height`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/image-transform-fit-to-height)
- Emacs bug reports: [`#18797`](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18797), [`#10746`](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10746), [`#10112`](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10112)

Answer (score 2):

`image-transform-set-scale` may be what you are looking for. However it requires Emacs to be compiled with Imagemagick support.

There is also a commented out `image-transform-mode` in `image-mode.el` labeled "Not yet implemented."

Comment: I see `Does Emacs use imagemagick?     yes` when running `./configure`. So it did compile with imagemagick. Still image transform doesn't work for me. *(On emacs 24.4 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)* I also have the following in `config.log`: `| #define HAVE_IMAGEMAGICK 1` `| #define HAVE_MAGICKEXPORTIMAGEPIXELS 1` `| #define HAVE_MAGICKMERGEIMAGELAYERS 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that lets you scale up and down using the same keys as are used for text scaling, C-x C-= and C-x C--

```
(defun scale-image ()
  "Scale the image by the same factor specified by the text scaling."
  (image-transform-set-scale
   (expt text-scale-mode-step
         text-scale-mode-amount)))

(defun scale-image-register-hook ()
  "Register the image scaling hook."
  (add-hook 'text-scale-mode-hook 'scale-image))

(add-hook 'image-mode-hook 'scale-image-register-hook)
```